# C# EF query for typical products - category relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, join

Using entity framework, trying to get some help for a query (prefer method based syntax) for this typical use case:

There is a products table, like:

- ownerId
- productId
- ProductCategoryId
- productInfo, etc.

There is a typical product-category-mapping table, like:

- somePrimaryKey
- ownerId
- categoryId
- productId
- sortOrder

This set up allows one product to be in multiple category, and has its own sort order in each category. Also, we have the "ownerId" in all tables since each owner can only see his own data.

Now, given a categtoryId and ownerId, we need to find all products of this category, sorted by the sortOrder.

Any way how we should write this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use something along those lines :

```
// Instanciate your context.
// Do it the way you've already done it, it's here only for example.
DbContext bd = new DbContext(); 

// The query :
List<Products> listProducts = new List<Products>();
listProducts = db.Products.Where(p => (db.ProductsCategories.Where(pc => pc.CategoryID == categoryID && pc.OwnerID == ownerID).Select(pc => pc.ProductID).OrderBy(pr => pr.sortOrder).ToList()).Contains(p.ProductID)).ToList();
```

This way use the product-category mapping (categorieID and ownerID are the datas you inject and you keep the sorting.

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts about performance for the Contains operator? Like, if there are thousands of products for a category. Or, will using some table join be better?

Comment: Obviously, if your table contains thousands of products, the Contains operator will iterate throught the whole list of id queryed from the ProductCategories table. So maybe a Join could be better for performance, but I think both will work. If you need help with Join, here's a link : [howToJoinMethodBased](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Just tested it and noticed one issue: looks like the sort does not work as expected - I think the Contains operator does not preserve the order.

Comment: I solved the sorting issue to sorting the results set again (basically I first get the productIds, then get the products, the sort the products based on the productIds). Thanks